# How can I install SABnzbd in elementary os

Tags: applications, appcenter, elementary-project, apps

How can I install this app in my elementary os?

Answer (score 1):

Open AppCentre and search for sabnzbd. Then click on "free" and it will install.

---

You can use the command line as well:

```
sudo apt install sabnzbdplus
```